# MS Access VBA: Closing Transaction without destroying Form's class module variables

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, transactions

I have an unbound form used to enter constituent data. I can't use subforms because data is spread across multiple tables and linked with foreign keys. Since I want to use the field validation rules to validate, I use a transaction to make sure new records are committed in an all-or-nothing fashion. I don't want names committed without addresses, etc.

The form is designed to iterate over a recordset, "tempImportRs", to give the user an opportunity to make sure the data looks OK and to manually correct or skip invalid entries. It works by populating the form's fields with values from tempImportRs for each entry. There's also a subform that searches for similar records and displays them to the user to decide if this is really a new person or if they already exist in the DB with somewhat different info.

I am running into a problem using this "tempImportRs" recordset, which persists for the lifetime of the form and is used by various methods in the form, alongside Access's transactions (which I don't understand very well, admittedly). If at any point I close the transaction like

```
WrkSp.Close
```

then my tempImportRs object will disappear and give me "Requires object" type errors. If I don't close the transaction, which is bad practice anyway, my form will work like I want for up to maybe a dozen records before giving me the error "Could not start transaction; too many transactions already nested."

**How can I close the transaction cleanly, without destroying "tempImportRs"?**

Here is a very simplified version of the VBA code for my form:

```
Public tempImportRs As RecordSet

Sub TryToAddRecords()
'Try to add the data from the now-populated form fields to my tables'
    On Error GoTo Error_TryToAddRecords

    Dim WrkSp As Workspace
    Set WrkSp = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
    WrkSp.BeginTrans

    'In my real code I use several recordsets to store the imported data'
    'but I am simplifying here by using just one:'

    Dim someOtherRs As Recordset
    Set someOtherRs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblNamesAddressesEtc")

    '...Do stuff using several other recordsets and '
    'the form fields populated from tempImportRs'

    someOtherRs.Update

    WrkSp.CommitTrans

    Exit_TryToAddRecords:

      someOtherRs.Close
      'I leave tempImportRs open for now.'

      'WrkSp.Close <--This is what messes up tempImportRs'
      Set someOtherRs = Nothing
      Set WrkSp = Nothing
      Exit Sub

    Error_TryToAddRecords:
      MsgBox Err.Description & vbNewLine & _
        "Please fix the field and try again."
      Resume Exit_TryToAddRecords

End Sub

Private Sub GoButton_click

    Set tempImportRs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTempImport")

    If !tempImportRs.EOF
        '<populate the form fields with the current '
        'tempImportRs data here>'
        TryToAddRecords
        tempImportRs.MoveNext
    Else
        tempImportRs.close
        Set tempImportRs = Nothing
        MsgBox "All records imported"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just bound the form to a temp table instead of iterating through a VBA recordset? Once validation passes by using the form's [BeforeInsert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835397.aspx) or individual control's [BeforeUpdate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822421.aspx) events (which are often used for data validation) append to final table. Otherwise, your process seems to reinvent the wheel of bounded forms (i.e., binding a recordset to a form) and require some resource overhead.

Comment: Shouldn't I keep validation rules at the table design level so that they're all in one place?

Comment: Even better! But in case customized validation requires some calculation, some do it at form level.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem specific to transactions and workspaces, but a more general matter of program structure. You should just make the workspace persist for the duration of the form, and commit to it multiple times. You don't need to make a new workspace for each transaction.

So, treat the workspace just like tempImportRs is treated in the code example. You can both set and close WrkSp in the GoButton_click sub. Don't set or close it in the TryToAddRecords function.

You will also have to make sure to roll back with WrkSp.Rollback if there's an error, add that line to Error_TryToAddRecords.

```
Public tempImportRs As RecordSet
Dim WrkSp As Workspace

'...

Private Sub GoButton_click

    Set tempImportRs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblTempImport")
    Set WrkSp = DBEngine.Workspaces(0) 'move this here

    If !tempImportRs.EOF
        '<populate the form fields with the current '
        'tempImportRs data here>'
        TryToAddRecords
        tempImportRs.MoveNext
    Else
        tempImportRs.Close
        Set tempImportRs = Nothing
        'close the workspace here when you're done with tempImportRs
        WrkSp.Close 
        Set WrkSp = Nothing
        MsgBox "All records imported"
    End If
End Sub
```

PS: Sorry folks for asking and answering this dumb question, I had a mental block and thought the issue was about managing workspaces and not a simpler matter of code design. Maybe this will still help someone someday.